# Using the IDENTITY() function in MySQL - can I include alphanumeric character in the function here such as this

Tags: mysql

Using the `IDENTITY()` function in wamp server MySQL, can I include alphanumeric character in the function here such as this?

```
ID int IDENTITY(T-0001,1),
```

- `T-0001` is the ID's value and
- `1` is the increment `+1`

instead of the regular syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe IDENTITY is MS SQL Server only, and not supported by MySQL; but I could be wrong.

Comment: which version of mysql  you are using?  .. because i hav never see this function

Comment: ok,thanks .What about the addition of numbers like 0001 increasing by +1.is it allowed?

Comment: i use the one in my wamp server,there are a lot of functions in sql just like in every other languages too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean but MySQL only has [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), which is integer values only. If you wanted to format those values to "T-0001", that should be more of a display issue.

Comment: Using `MyISAM` engine, you can use 2 columns as PK: `CREATE TABLE Persons (prefix ENUM('T-') NOT NULL, ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(255), Age INT, PRIMARY KEY (prefix,ID)) ENGINE=MyISAM;`. Then, as said Uueerdo, it's a matter of display.